# Transferring environment variable through SSH / quoting in bash/sh/csh/tcsh

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, tcsh, csh, escaping

I want to transfer an environment variable over SSH.

The "correct" way is using SendEnv/`~/.ssh/environment`, but that requires the server to support AcceptEnv or PermitUserEnvironment, which it does not in my case.

So instead I am thinking to set the variable on the remote site like this:

```
FOO=val
export FOO
ssh server export FOO=$FOO'; do_stuff_which_uses_FOO'
```

That part is easy. I want a generic solution, so no matter the content of $FOO it will work. E.g.

```
FOO="  '\""
export FOO
QFOO=`quote "$FOO"` # quote will return "\ \ \'\\\""
export QFOO
ssh server export FOO=$QFOO'; do_stuff_which_uses_FOO'
```

This works no matter if the sending or receiving shell is sh or bash.

However, I also need it to work for csh/tcsh. And I will not know in advance which shell the receiving end is running. That means I have to code something that will work both in /bin/sh and /bin/csh.

So far I have managed to get it working for sh/bash:

```
ssh server // followed by the below quoted
eval `echo $SHELL | grep -E "/(t)?csh" > /dev/null && echo setenv FOO \\\ \\\ \\\\\'\\\\\" || echo export FOO=\\\ \\\ \\\\\'\\\\\";` ; echo "$FOO"
```

I can also get it to work for csh/tcsh (the user `csh` has csh as login shell):

```
ssh csh@server // followed by the below quoted
eval `echo $SHELL | grep -E "/(t)?csh" > /dev/null && echo setenv FOO \\\ \\\ \\\\\'\\\\\" || echo export FOO=\\\ \\\ \\\\\'\\\\\";` ; echo "$FOO"
```

If $FOO is * or ? it works fine with BASH:

```
ssh server eval\ \`echo\ \$SHELL\ \|\ grep\ -E\ \"/\(t\)\?csh\"\ \>\ /dev/null\ \&\&\ echo\ setenv\ FOO\ \\\\\\\\\\\*\\\;\ \|\|\ echo\ export\ FOO=\\\\\\\\\\\*\\\;\`\;echo\ \"\$FOO\"\ a;
```

But it fails with csh:

```
ssh csh@server eval\ \`echo\ \$SHELL\ \|\ grep\ -E\ \"/\(t\)\?csh\"\ \>\ /dev/null\ \&\&\ echo\ setenv\ FOO\ \\\\\\\\\\\*\\\;\ \|\|\ echo\ export\ FOO=\\\\\\\\\\\*\\\;\`\;echo\ \"\$FOO\"\ a;
No match.
FOO: Undefined variable.
```

It seems * and ? refuse to be quoted with .

To answer this question your solution should:

- be able to transfer an environment variable to the remote server
- not use SendEnv/AcceptEnv/PermitUserEnvironment
- work no matter if the source shell is sh/bash/csh/tcsh
- work no matter if the destination shell is sh/bash/csh/tcsh
- work no matter the content of the environment variable. Specifically it should at least work for: \n * space ' " ? < > ! $ \ and any combination of those.

If you can find a better way to transfer the variable than quoting it, then that is fine, too.

Comment: It sounds like we're doing your homework.  Why can you not use the ssh SendEnv or AcceptEnv options?  That's what they are DESIGNED for.

Comment: It is to be used for --env in GNU Parallel. GNU Parallel is used by estimated 25000 users. A lot of these users do not have root access on the systems they are using (often it is compute clusters). If AcceptEnv had not required root access then I would agree. As you can see below I have found a solution that works for all but \n.

Comment: Ah, that make sense.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a working model for all characters except \n:

```
sub shell_quote_scalar {
    # Quote the string so shell will not expand any special chars
    # Returns:
    #   string quoted with \ as needed by the shell
    my $a = shift;
    $a =~ s/([\002-\011\013-\032\\\#\?\`\(\)\{\}\[\]\*\>\<\~\|\; \"\!\$\&\'\202-\377])/\\$1/g;
    $a =~ s/[\n]/'\n'/g; # filenames with '\n' is quoted using \'
    return $a;
}

sub env_quote {
    my $v = shift;
    $v =~ s/([ \n\&\<\>\(\)\;\'\{\}\t\"\$\`\*\174\!\?\~])/\\$1/g;
    return $v;
}

my @qcsh = map { my $a=$_; "setenv $a " . env_quote($ENV{$a})  } @vars;
my @qbash = map { my $a=$_; "export $a=" . env_quote($ENV{$a}) } @vars;

$Global::envvar =
    join"",
    (q{echo $SHELL | grep -E "/t?csh" > /dev/null && }
     . join(" && ", @qcsh)
     . q{ || }
     . join(" && ", @qbash)
     .q{;});

print shell_quote_scalar($Global::envvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just base64-encode the variable? The easiest way to deal with this is probably to simply treat the data as binary.

```
export QFOO=`echo $FOO | base64 --wrap=0`
ssh server "export FOO=`echo \"$QFOO\" | base64 --decode --wrap=0`; <command>"
```

You might have to fiddle with the quoting on the `ssh` line, but that's the gist of it. This should remove shell specifics with regards to quoting, but might introduce some with sub-commands (I'm not much familiar with anything outside of `bash`)

Comment: Not a bad idea. Though I probably cannot assume base64 is installed (base64 is part of GNU coreutils and only introduced 2006 - thus we cannot assume it is installed on non-GNU systems and on pre-2006 GNU systems). I can, however, assume an old version of Perl is installed, so using (un)pack with template "u*", that should be doable.

Comment: uuencoded strings include *. ARGH! But hex encoded should work.

Comment: I cannot find a way to make this work: As the command need to work under both csh and bash, I need to eval it. And as soon as I eval it then the * and ? will cause problems in csh.  `echo setenv U` `perl -e '($a="212223c2a425262f28293d410a417b5b5d7d5e7e2a41") =~ s/(..)/chr hex $1/eg;print $a'`

Comment: @OleTange Is `openssl` available? http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030721010526390

Comment: Nope. But even if base64 was available it would not fix the issue: I still need to do the eval and it is that step that breaks in (t)csh if the variable contains * or ? (Bash works fine, and so does csh/tcsh as long as the variable does not contain * or ?).