# Exporting bash functions through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

So I found a way to transfer environment variables through ssh without having to change neither server nor client: [Transferring environment variable through SSH / quoting in bash/sh/csh/tcsh](https://superuser.com/questions/482481/transferring-environment-variable-through-ssh-quoting-in-bash-sh-csh-tcsh)

But I would also like to be able to transfer bash functions like this one:

```
$ myfunc() {
> echo Func $1
> }
$ export -f myfunc
$ parallel myfunc ::: a
Func a
```

Functions are not transferred through ssh:

```
$ parallel -S server myfunc ::: a
bash: myfunc: command not found
$ parallel --env myfunc -S server myfunc ::: a
bash: line 2: myfunc: command not found
```

But the content of the function is transferred nicely:

```
$ parallel --env myfunc -S server echo \$myfunc ::: a
() { echo Func $1} a
```

So it seems all I need to do now is to somehow tell bash that $myfunc is really the function myfunc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually proved to be fairly easy (except it does not work in csh). Simply do:

```
eval myfunc$myfunc
```

It unfortunately crashes normal variables, to avoid this only do the eval for variables for which the content start with '() {'; that seems to be bash's signature for functions.

Comment: Today use `env_parallel` from GNU Parallel. It works for more than functions.