# Export bash function over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

I would like to export a bash function over ssh to use it in GNU parallel. That question seems to be answered here

[Exporting bash functions through ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/620782/exporting-bash-functions-through-ssh?lq=1)

but I don't seem to be able to get it to work. Where does the eval needs to be placed? Would it be possible to provide a full example of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the tutorial:
http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#transfer_environment_variables_and_functions

```
Using --env GNU Parallel can transfer an environment variable to the remote system.
```